# Custom adapter doesn't change text in listview

Tags: java, android, firebase, listview, arraylist

I'm trying to show the data i got from the firebase in a listview. But my textview in listview doesn't change. This output i have two document my database. Two listview appear but can't change text.Where am i wrong?

[OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TiySj.png)

Here's my **CustomAdapter code**

```
public class MissionsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Missions> {

public MissionsAdapter(Context context, List<Missions> object){
    super(context,0, object);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    if(convertView == null){
        convertView =  ((Activity)getContext()).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_missions,parent,false);
    }
    Missions mission = getItem(position);
    TextView titleTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.mission_title);
    TextView expTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.mission_exp);
    TextView dateTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.mission_date);
    TextView descriptionTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.mission_description);
    TextView bilgitext=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.mission_bilgi);

    titleTextView.setText(mission.getTitle());
    expTextView.setText(mission.getExp());
    dateTextView.setText(mission.getDate());
    descriptionTextView.setText(mission.getDescription());
    bilgitext.setText(mission.getBilgi());

    return convertView;
}
```

}

**Missions.java**

```
public class Missions {

public String title;
public String exp;
public String date;
public String description;
public String bilgi;

public Missions() {}

public Missions(String title, String exp, String date, String description, String bilgi) {
    this.title = title;
    this.exp = exp;
    this.date = date;
    this.description = description;
    this.bilgi=bilgi;
}

public String getTitle(){
    return title;
}
public String getExp(){
    return exp;
}
public String getDate(){
    return date;
}
public String getDescription(){
    return description;
}
public String getBilgi(){
    return bilgi;
}
```

}

**item_missions.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="16dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/mission_title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"

    android:hint="There will be a title"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/mission_exp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearance"

    android:hint="There will be exp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/mission_date"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearance"

    android:hint="There will be a date"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/mission_description"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearance"
    android:hint="There will be a description"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/mission_bilgi"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearance"
    android:hint="There will be a bilgi"/>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/missionHeader"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Edit/Create mission"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    />


<ListView
    android:id="@+id/missionList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</ListView>
```

**And finally MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity5 extends AppCompatActivity {
    private final String COLLECTION_KEY = "İlanlar";
    private TextView mHeaderView;
    private ListView mMissionListView;
    private FirebaseFirestore db;
    private MissionsAdapter mMissionAdapter;
    private ArrayList<Missions> mMissionsList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main5);

        mHeaderView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.missionHeader);
        mMissionListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.missionList);
        mHeaderView.setText("Available Missions");
        db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
       
        mMissionsList = new ArrayList<Missions>();
        mMissionAdapter = new MissionsAdapter(MainActivity5.this, mMissionsList);
        mMissionListView.setAdapter(mMissionAdapter);

        db.collection(COLLECTION_KEY).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                List<Missions> mMissionsList = new ArrayList<>();
                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                    for(QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                        Missions miss = document.toObject(Missions.class);
                        mMissionsList.add(miss);
                    }
                    ListView mMissionsListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.missionList);
                    MissionsAdapter mMissionAdapter = new MissionsAdapter(MainActivity5.this, mMissionsList);
                    mMissionsListView.setAdapter(mMissionAdapter);

                } else {
                    Log.d("MissionActivity", "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                }
            }
        });
        mMissionAdapter.addAll(mMissionsList);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "can't change text"?

Comment: mMissionAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); add this after adding data in arraylist